# find max&min possible value of specific date/time in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

i have a datetime column in my table and im performing between lookup on it.

here is example data from my table (events)

```
id  owner  date
1   formA  2014-11-10 15:45:00
2   formB  2014-11-14 16:00:00
3   formC  2014-11-17 19:30:00
4   formD  2014-11-19 21:10:00
5   formE  2014-11-20 12:10:00
```

i want to show today's events and the events from 2 days ago. **today - 2days**.

in order to archieve my needs i need to find today's max possible value for time.

let's say that current time is 2014-11-20 11:00:00,

i need to find max value for that time which is 2014-11-20 23:59:59 so i can include whole today's time to query.

same thing applies to -days of the time.

2014-11-20 11:00:00 - 2 days equals to 2014-11-18 11:00:00.

so i need to find minimum possible value of the time which is 2014-11-18 00:00:00 in order to include that day from the start.

i can do it with the following procedure but it's a quite long to implement.

```
// current date
$end_date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$start_date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
// intervals. (1day - 1second so i can find)
$diff1day = new DateInterval('PT86399S');
$diff2day = new DateInterval('P2D');
// apply intervals
$end_date = $end_date->add($diff1day);
$start_date = $start_date->sub($diff12day);
// format to use in sql query
$end_date = $end_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$start_date = $start_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

code above outputs:

```
$end_date ->   2014-11-20 23:59:59
$start_date -> 2014-11-18 00:00:00
```

which is exactly i need.

**is this approach ok?
is there any shorter way to archieve this?**

thanks.

Comment: I usually just hard-code the strings `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` in my programs. Do you really need to compute these?

Comment: well, i actually don't. i hard-coded the time strings first time i implemented it. but im trying to avoid using hard-coded things in my projects. thats why im seeking a native way to accomplish it. thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I don't think the times of the beginning and end of the day are ever going to change.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can Solve this even in your MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAYS)
```

Comment: i've tested your solution and it performed very well. thanks! BETWEEN is a little bit faster but it doesn't matter in my environment. also it can't catch starting value of "2 days before" which is also doesn't matter. (2014-11-18 00:00:00, should be +1 miliseconds in order to be catched by the query. -> 2014-11-18 00:00:0**1**)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you a little bit :)

```
$date1 = '2014-11-20';
$date2 = '2014-11-18';

$days = ( strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
```